# How to find the shortest path with multiple edges between two nodes?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, shortest-path

I am trying to generate the **shortest path** but I need to generate **dummy nodes** to do this as I have **several edges** from Istanbul to Ankara so I am unable to create a path using the normal method since the model considers those edges as one edge.
My nodes are shown in the first two columns of the excel sheet (Node1 and Node2). I wanted to generate the shortest path using Node1_reference and Node2_reference but I am unsure how to go about it or whether I should create dummy nodes as I am unable to call the cities without the suffixes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is to use a `nx.MultiDigraph`, a directed multi graph which can hold several parallel edges between two nodes.

```
# Add nodes
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_node('Istanbul')
g.add_node('Ankara')
g.add_node('Muscat')

# Add edges
g.add_edge('Istanbul', 'Ankara', data=dict(time=1, route=1))
g.add_edge('Istanbul', 'Ankara', data=dict(time=2, route=2))
g.add_edge('Istanbul', 'Ankara', data=dict(time=10, route=3))
g.add_edge('Istanbul', 'Muscat', data=dict(time=20, route=1))
g.add_edge('Istanbul', 'Muscat', data=dict(time=20, route=2))
g.add_edge('Ankara', 'Muscat', data=dict(time=2, route=1))
```

Now we have multiple edges from one city to another. The trick is to specify how the weight function has to behave when querying the graph for shortest paths: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html

```
def weight_func(u, v, d):
    for v in d.values():
        if v['data']['route'] == 1:
            return v['data']['time']
    return None

result = nx.shortest_path(g, source=None, target=None, weight=weight_func)
print(result)
```

Basically, when the algorithm evaluates all the parallel edges between nodes `[u, v]`, we get the list of data properties for these edges, then we loop over them and filter so we can return the weight we want.

You can wrap this function in another higher-level function to make it more convenient like so:

```
def filter_route_id(route):
    def weight_func(u, v, d):
        for v in d.values():
            if v['data']['route'] == route:
                return v['data']['time']
        return None
    return weight_func

result = nx.shortest_path(g, source=None, target=None, weight=filter_route_id(1))
print(result)
```

> {'Istanbul': {'Istanbul': ['Istanbul'], 'Ankara': ['Istanbul', 'Ankara'], 'Muscat': ['Istanbul', 'Ankara', 'Muscat']}, 'Ankara': {'Ankara': ['Ankara'], 'Muscat': ['Ankara', 'Muscat']}, 'Muscat': {'Muscat': ['Muscat']}}